# SDL: How to create simpli slider and manipulate its position via mouse?

Tags: c++, mouse, slider, sdl, trackbar

So I want to create a gui for my game. I want to create a draggable slider. How to do such thing having 2 images - track and ball?

Answer (score 0):

Use some of SDL gui library rather than write another one. Here is [small list](http://www.libsdl.org/libraries.php?order=name&category=-1&completed=0&os=-1&match_name=gui&perpage=50): 
[CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page),
[GuiChan](http://guichan.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Or you can try implement SDL into Qt.